# How can I get the browser scrollbar height in javascript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

How can I get the browser scrollbar height? Does JS have a built-in function for this case?
Somebody please help me out of this.

Comment: Please see this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes

Comment: @varu This is about scrollbar width.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript/22510143#22510143

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method for this. However, the scrollbar's height is *supposed* to give an indication of how much of the available content fits within the available viewport. Going by that, we can determine it like:

```
var sbHeight = window.innerHeight * (window.innerHeight / document.body.offsetHeight);
```

Where `window.innerHeight / document.body.offsetHeight` is the percentage of content visible currently. We multiple that with the available viewport height to get the approximate scrollbar height.

Note: Different browsers may add/reduce some pixels to/from the scrolbar height.

Comment: I suppose there is a mistake here. For example, I've got a window with innerHeight  = 500 and body.offsetHeight = 2000 so I get scrollbar's height = 500 * (500 / 2000) = 125 px. And if body.offsetHeight = 100 than I get scrollbar's height = 2500. It is too much for a scrollbar, isn't it?

Comment: isn't it supposed to be scrollHeight to get the percentage visible ?

Answer (score 5):

```
'window.pageYOffset'
```

returns the current height of the scrollbar concerning the full height of the document.
A simple example of usage is like

```
alert('Current scroll from the top: ' + window.pageYOffset)
```

Comment: Tested your code it shows "driver is not defined", can please check your code ?

Answer (score -5):

Does this help?

```
this.document.body.scrollHeight
```

Comment: This is a full height of the content available for scrolling.

Comment: element.scrollHeight