# How can I get the final css property used for a dom node?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the final css property applied to a dom node, but not the calculated value. I know that `getComputedStyle` can get a computed value, but this isn't what I want. Here's an example:

```
<body>
  <div id='x' class="a b">x</div>
</body>
<style>
 .a {
   height: auto;
 }
 .b {
   height: 35%;
 }
</style>
```

I want to be able to find that '35%' value for my x div, not the pixel height. How can I do this in javascript? Is there an easy way or do you have to traverse the classes and stylesheets yourself?

Comment: You'll always get the final number, in pixels. If you want something else, calculate it yourself, percentage is just based on the parent height etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 I've tried researching how to do it. The only way I can think of involves traversing all the stylesheets and classes, which I really don't want to have to do

Comment: what are you trying to do? why/what do you need that value for *(rather than the computed one)*?

Comment: @Thomas I'm trying to calculate the maximum height a dom node can take up without going outside the boundaries of its parent. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514761/calculating-the-maximum-minimum-height-of-a-div-element/39782139#39782139

Comment: @Terry The 3rd answer there looks promising, I'm trying that out.

Comment: Alright, the answer where you hide the parent then use getComputedStyle worked for me (then you unhide the parent).