# Convert vh units to px in JS

Tags: javascript, css, viewport-units

Unfortunately `100vh` is not always the same as `100%` browser height as can be shown in the following example.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow: scroll;
}

.vh {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100px;
}

.pc {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh"></div>
<div class="pc"></div>
```

The issue is more pronounced on iPhone 6+ with how the upper location bar and lower navigation bar expand and contract on scroll, but are not included in the calculation for `100vh`.

The actual value of `100%` height can be acquired by using `window.innerHeight` in JS.

**Is there a convenient way to calculate the current conversion of `100vh` to pixels in JS?**

I'm trying to avoid needing to generate dummy elements with inline styles just to calculate `100vh`.

For purposes of this question, assume a hostile environment where `max-width` or `max-height` may be producing incorrect values, and there isn't an existing element with `100vh` anywhere on the page. Basically, assume that anything that can go wrong *has* with the exception of native browser functions, which are guaranteed to be clean.

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
function vh() {
    var div,
        h;
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.height = '100vh';
    div.style.maxHeight = 'none';
    div.style.boxSizing = 'content-box';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    h = div.clientHeight;
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    return h;
}
```

but it seems far too verbose for calculating the current value for `100vh`, and I'm not sure if there are other issues with it.

Comment: Why do you need to get the pixel equivalent of `100vh` anyway?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
function viewportToPixels(value) {
  var parts = value.match(/([0-9\.]+)(vh|vw)/)
  var q = Number(parts[1])
  var side = window[['innerHeight', 'innerWidth'][['vh', 'vw'].indexOf(parts[2])]]
  return side * (q/100)
}
```

Usage:

```
viewportToPixels('100vh') // window.innerHeight
viewportToPixels('50vw') // window.innerWidth / 2
```

Comment: Wrong, `innerHeight` is not `100vh` on iOS http://output.jsbin.com/diwoyevive/quiet

Comment: @yckart you are right, but it could be useful to solve this problem : https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d ; thus, replacing `100vh` with `innerHeight` it is the solution used by react-div-100vh component

Answer (score -1):

The difference comes from the scrollbar.

You'll need to add the height of the scrollbar to the `window.innerHeight`. There doesn't seem to be a super solid way of doing this, per this other question:

[Getting scroll bar width using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript)

Comment: There are a variety of other browser features in addition to scroll bars that cause 100vh to differ significantly from 100% height.

Comment: what else is there?

Comment: I covered a couple in the question. Particularly the iPhone location and navigation bars which make 100% height smaller, but do not affect 100vh.