# How to remove resizing content when overflow when is hover?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with overflow in on my website. When mouse is not over the left menu, it look OK, but when I move mouse over the menu and `:hover` is active, content (menu is a content) is a little smaller. I don't want this effect when `:hover` is active, menu is a little smaller.

Effect that I want is like on Youtube. If you are logged into your account, and if you pressed menu icon next to Youtube logo, you will get scroll menu. When mouse is not over the menu, nothing happens. But when you move your mouse over the menu, overflow is visible and this not change content size.

In brief:

1. I have this:

[image: this image]

when overflow is active, content is smaller

2. What I want is this:

[image: this image]

when overflow is active, content is NOT smaller

How can I do it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: check on active of `:hover` if you are adding something?

Comment: I have just that in my css:

nav {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

nav:hover {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, though it maybe flawed is that you have to already have the space that the scroll bar will populate there. You didn't give us any code so I had to fabricate it, but this is what I came up with

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/bxz60j4r/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="http://moss-side.yoursquaremile.co.uk/img/default-profile-pic.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png" />
      <span>Test card data</span>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png" />
      <span>Test card data</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png" />
      <span>Test card data</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png" />
      <span>Test card data</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png" />
      <span>Test card data</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar .container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #8cc34b;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}

.card {
  opacity: .7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #8cc34b;
}

.card span {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  top: 50%;
}

hr {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-color: darkgreen;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

Comment: In your example i can see that what i want: You can see my problem here: http://adrian-gradek.tk/ Menu change size after hover and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Yes i see. And that's a problem, content when is :hover change size

Comment: I think the problem arises because it's not fixed width so you can't (easily) trick it

Comment: See if we set the size (oppose to using percentage) https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/d82sf4u3/1/ we can use padding instead of changing the size

Comment: So i cant use percent to set a width ?

Comment: I used percent because i wanted to autoscale my website at different resolution.

Comment: ah I'd use media queries for that, much better control https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Then when it gets down to phone size you can take way the space for the scroll bar as phones don't use then the same :-)

Comment: I'm useing media queries for mobile now :) If you zoom in (ctrl + scroll up) you will see that :) It's not perfect but work :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/b92w8tz8/ ah ok here's a quick example anyway :-)

Comment: Or can we get scrollbar outside ?

Comment: Ok wait :) I'm trying to do that :) I thing I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```css
.scrollable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px; /* specify the width you like here */
  overfow: hidden;
}

.scrollable:hover {
  overfow-y: scroll;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 80px; /* specify the width which is calculated as widthOfScrollable - widthOfScrollbar */
}

.item1, .item2 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item1 { background: red }
.item2 { background: blue }
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <nav>
    <li class="item1"></li>
    <li class="item2"></li>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Borders and colors are used to show the blocks.

Here you preserve some space for the scrollbar on the right side. Problem here is to preserve exactly the scrollbar size for the current user / browser / OS. They all could have differences in scrollbar width value, so there are two ways for you to go:

1. Use this function from here [Getting scroll bar width using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript) to calculate the proper size of the scrollbar
2. Make the scrollbar margin big enough to cover any case on any operating system