# Whats default scrollbar width on IE and Firefox?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I am wondering what is the default scrollbar width on IE and Firefox. I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes), but it always returns `0`.

Comment: It's system-dependent. Each OS has some default chrome (UI elements, such as scrollbars). There is no universal "default" value.

Comment: Its been already asked and answered. Please follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript) link